# Find the parameters in $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}f(x)\,dx\approx w_1f(x_1)+w_2f(x_2)$ such that the formula will be exact for $\sin(2x),\sin(x),\cos(x),1$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

> Consider the following integration rule on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$: $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}f(x)\,dx\approx w_1f(x_1)+w_2f(x_2).$$ Find the parameters such that the formula will be exact for $\sin(2x),\sin(x),\cos(x),1$.

I've done the following system of equations
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}1\,dx=\pi=w_1+w_2\tag{1}\\
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\,dx=2=w_1\cos(x_1)+w_2\cos(x_2)\tag{2}\\
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\,dx=0=w_1\sin(x_1)+w_2\sin(x_2)\tag{3}\\
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(2x)\,dx=0=w_1\sin(2x_1)+w_2\sin(2x_2)\tag{4}
\end{align}
I've tried to solve the system but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A start for a solution:

Expand $(4)$
$$
2w_1\sin(x_1)\cos(x1) = -2w_2\sin(x_2)\cos(x_2)
\tag{$4'$}$$
Rewrite $(3)$
$$
w_2\sin(x_2) = -w_1\sin(x_1)
\tag{$3'$}$$
Substitute $(3')$ into $(4'$)
$$
2w_1\sin(x_1)\cos(x_1) = 2w_1\sin(x_1)\cos(x_2)
$$
Then reduce to three cases:
(A) $w_1 = 0$;
(B) $\sin(x_1)=0$ so $x_1 = 0$;
(C) $\cos(x_1) = \cos(x_2)$ so $x_1=-x_2$.

Try to continue...

---

I get:
$$
w_1=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
w_2=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
x_1=\arccos\frac{2}{\pi}\\
x_2=-\arccos\frac{2}{\pi}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much  :)